# MSBUILD target outputs element is applied strangly

Tags: c#, msbuild, element, target

Hi I have my C# project in Visual Studio 2012 where I want to copy some external dlls to my bin folder.

For a clean build it copies everything to bin folder without problems.

Then I delete some dll file and run incremental build. Visual studio says everything up to date and missing dll is not copied.

Here is the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build;CopyFiles" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
...  
<ItemGroup>
  <AvailableItemName Include="RootContent">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </AvailableItemName>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <RootContent Include="External Dlls\sqlceca40.dll">
    </RootContent>
    <RootContent Include="External Dlls\sqlcecompact40.dll">
    </RootContent>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name="CopyFiles" Inputs="@(RootContent)" Outputs="@(RootContent -> '$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy DestinationFiles="@(RootContent -> '$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SourceFiles="@(RootContent)"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Do you know what I am missing? Thanks.